# Nifi Processor with multiple inputs, triggers only after receiving certain flow files

Tags: apache-nifi

I am receiving tar files from FTP and saving it to HDFS after extracting it. So My current pipeline looks like this.

ListFTP -> FetchFTP -> UnpackContent -> PutHDFS

This tar contains 10 files and hence for a single tar file, 10 flow files are generated. My requirement is to trigger another job after 3 particular files are stored in HDFS. Which Processor should I use or is there any other approach to this problem using Nifi?

Comment: What's your problem? Do you want to merge the files into 3 per batch or you are okay with the files being written as 10 different files and you just want to trigger a job after a 3 specific files are written to HDFS?

Comment: I just want to trigger a job after a 3 specific files are written to HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using RouteOnAttribute, Notify and Wait processors. The complete flow is described below.

ListFTP -> FetchFTP -> UnpackContent -> PutHDFS -> RouteOnAttribute -> Notify -> Wait ->

- **RouteOnAttribute:** Reroute the 3 required files to a seperate queue using the following.

${filename:equals('file1.tsv'):or(${filename:equals('file2.tsv')}):or(${filename:equals('file3.tsv')})}

- **Notify:** This is used to notify that a particular file is received. Set the Signal Counter Name as ${filename}.
- **Notify:** This processor will wait till all the 3 files are received and after that will trigger a flowfile.